# unsigned char to enum

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on a network program and I have this code in my thread pool

```
unsigned char type = pdata[0];
Packet *packet = m_packetFactory->createInstance(type);
```

CreateInstance take an enum type to crate a packet based on the enum variable;

Client is using java and serialize the first byte like this

```
 final byte LOGIN_REQUEST = 1;
 .
 .
 bBuffer.put(LOGIN_REQUEST);
```

How do I get this in enum type so I can pass that into createInstance method..Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the problem using typecast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure the data is valid, simply cast it to the enum type:

```
enum MyEnum{
  EXAMPLE_1 = 0,
  ...
};

char type = 0;
MyEnum etype = static_cast<MyEnum>(type);
```